# Store image in localstorage **without** converting to Base64 and referencing in HTML as path?

Tags: javascript, base64, local-storage, offline

**Question..**

Is it possible to store an image in localstorage (or any browser based storage mechanism) **without** converting it to Base64 and referencing this image in HTML as path (not as inline data)?

**The reason..**

I am working with a WYSIWYG editor that can display Base64 images (in it's contenteditable div).

It works.. But it degrades performance a bunch. The data string inlined in the HTML `img src` chokes the WYSIWYG performance, whereas an `img` tag with a path string as `src` would not cause this issue.

For reasons I won't get into, I have the requirement to store the images locally and only locally.

**Other solutions?..**
Localstorage AFAIK is limited to storing serialized data (strings) so my guess is this is a dead end. But perhaps there any other solutions?

**Edit**
**I do not need to upload images to server**. This app will be entirely offline.The app will store data (JSON and images) locally only.

Comment: You really cannot, AFAIK, and I see `offline` tagged but that doesn't mean you can upload the image to your server, and update its value (in a session, perhaps)

Comment: I've updated my question, hopefully I've clarified my usecase. Uploading is not necessary.

Comment: Take a look at [converting base64 to blob](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/2151050). [Browser support (just in case you care about IE)](http://caniuse.com/blob)